# Is it possible to print using different colors in ipython's Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is it somehow possible to have certain output appear in a different color in the IPython Notebook?
For example, something along the lines of:

```
 print("Hello Red World", color='red')
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The notebook has, of course, its own syntax highlighting. So I would be careful when using colour elsewhere, just to avoid making things harder to read for yourself or someone else (e.g., output should simply be in black, but you get parts in red if there is an exception).

But (to my surprise), it appears that you can use ANSI escape codes (even in the browser). At least, I could:

On the default Python prompt:

```
>>> print("\x1b[31m\"red\"\x1b[0m")
"red"
```

In the notebook:

```
In [28]: print("\x1b[31m\"red\"\x1b[0m")
         "red"
```

(Obviously, I cheated here with the syntax highlighting of SO so that "red" is printed in the colour red in both examples. I don't think SO allows a user to set a colour for text.)

I wouldn't really know another way to get colours.

For more on ANSI escape codes, I'd suggest the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). And if you find the above to verbose, you can of course write a wrapper function around this.

Comment: @cgseller For IPython 5.1.0 in the terminal notebook (`jupyter console`), this still works for me. What notebook & version are you referring to?

Comment: If it works for you too that is great.  I only confirmed latest

Comment: @laike9m Please mention your Jupyter version, and how you are running the notebook.

Comment: I use the latest version(installed yesterday via pip) and run with `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: @laike9m I've just tested with Python 3.6 and Jupyter 4.4.1 (IPython 5.3.0), in various browsers (on macOS). The example in my answer still works in all cases. I assume you copy-pasted the example, to avoid typos? There may something in your configuration, in which case you may want to ask a new question about it here on StackOverflow. You probably will have to dig into various configuration details for that to be answered, though.

Comment: I only test on Windows+Chrome, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: There are many libraries that already wrap this.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54065462/2800876 for an example.

Comment: It's hard to add these characters directly to the string, so you can just move them to the vars and use them in the template.

`_red = "\x1b[31m\""; red_ = "\"\x1b[0m"; print(f"No rule {_red}{item}{red_} in rules")`

Answer (score 63):

You can use this library [termcolor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) and you can get all other official libraries of python in PyPi.

> 1. `pip install termcolor`
> 2. then goto `ipython`

**Code**

```
from termcolor import colored
print(colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green'))
print(colored("hello red world", 'red'))
```

**Output:**

```
hello world
hello red world
```

The first argument is what you want to print on console and second argument use that color.

See the documentation in `pypi.python.org` for more information

Comment: Does it work in Jupyter notebook? Or only Jupyter interpreter?

Comment: works with both only thing is that you must have that library termcolor

Comment: Interesting, which Jupyter version are you having? ANSI wasn't working on my other laptop in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: 4.2.0 version of jupyter

Comment: [**colorama**](https://github.com/tartley/colorama) is another similar library which let's you do things like `print(Fore.RED + 'some red text');
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')` or `print(colored('Hello, World!', 'green', 'on_red'))`.

Comment: works but only supports seven colors: red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white

Comment: @anandtripathi, can this approach be generalized to display colored text in lists and dicts rather than via print?

Answer (score 38):

Similar to what @alvas mentioned but simpler

```
from IPython.display import Markdown
display (Markdown('this is in <span style="color: #ff0000">red</span> color.'))
```

Comment: Because the question asks specifically about Jupyter notebooks, this should be *the* answer

Comment: Agree, no need for an extra library

Comment: It's not working with VS Code notebooks. If I use `HTML` instead of `Markdown` all works fine.

Answer (score 37):

Here's a quick hack:

```
from IPython.display import HTML as html_print

def cstr(s, color='black'):
    return "<text style=color:{}>{}</text>".format(color, s)

left, word, right = 'foo' , 'abc' , 'bar'
html_print(cstr(' '.join([left, cstr(word, color='red'), right]), color='black') )
```

[out]:

[image]

If you just want a single color: `html_print(cstr('abc', 'red'))`

Answer (score 32):

In the Jupiter notebook, we can use a color marker to print the output in different colors
There are three ways that we can use a color marker.

let's see how to print a yellow color in a notebook.

1. `print('\033[93m output')`
2. `print('\033[93m' 'output')`
3. `print('\033[93m' + 'output')`

Some of the colors are :

- **yellow = '\033[93m'**
- **green = '\033[92m'**
- **red = '\033[91m'**
- blue = '\033[94m'
- pink = '\033[95m'

you can change the last number and get other colors as well.

[image]

Comment: The standard colors are black=0, red=1, green=2, yellow=3, blue=4, magenta=5, cyan=6, white=7. 9 means 'off' or default. To set the foreground color, use ESCAPE (that's the \033 above), "[", 30+ the color number, and "m". For background color, it's 40 + the color number instead. When you're done, turn the color back off with 39 or 49, or leave out the number entirely. Other numbers can get you special effect like bold, italics, blink,....

Comment: Simple and without additional workarounds. I think this should be the main answer.

Comment: The thing is that with this solution, it will keep using the same color if you print it in the same cell

Comment: After the use you have to turn the color back off as explained by @TextGeek in 1st comment.

Answer (score 14):

Not with raw Python print. You will have to define a `_repr_html_` on an object and return it  or call `IPython.lib.display(object_with_repr_html)`.

I guess you could overwrite the built-in print to do it automatically...

You could inspire from http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5098827, code [in a gist on github](https://gist.github.com/takluyver/5098835), ML discussion [here](http://lists.ipython.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2013-March/012293.html).

Comment: @Evert's code works in the current head version of ipython notebook - can we assume this functionality has been added?

Comment: Yes, the parsing of ANSI escape code has been there for a while, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 10):

There is the [colored library](https://pypi.org/project/colored/) (`pip install colored`), which you can use to modify a string to get color codes to modify how it is printed.  Example use:

```
import colored
print(colored.bg("white") + colored.fg("red") + "Hello world!")
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @alvas function and adding another function we get a very simple way to print

```
from IPython.display import HTML as html_print
from IPython.display import display

def cstr(s, color='black'):
    return "<text style=color:{}>{}</text>".format(color, s)

def print_color(t):
    display(html_print(' '.join([cstr(ti, color=ci) for ti,ci in t])))

print_color((('hello my name is', 'black'),('jhjfd','red')))
print_color((('hello my name is', 'green'),))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[`colorama`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) makes it dead easy:

```py
from colorama import Fore
print(Fore.RED + "this is red")
```

Answer (score 4):

**Text in red:**

```
print("\x1b[31mText in red")
```

**Text in bold:**

```
print("\x1B[1mText in bold")
```

**Text in underline**

```
print("\x1B[4mText in underline")
```

See [here](https://tforgione.fr/posts/ansi-escape-codes/) under Styles and Colors chapter and see what works for you. RGB colors didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using @Evert answer, here is a method that would wrap a list of tokens in red and return a highlighted string

```
def color_in_tokens(tokens, color_token_contains="_"):
  """
  Highlights the tokens which contain 'color_token_contains'

  :param tokens: list of strings
  :param color_token_contains: str (the string for marking a token red)
  :return: str
  """
  return " ".join(["\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m" % i if color_token_contains in i else i for i in tokens])
```

Just call print on the returned string:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A nice way is to use `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd
def apply_formatting(col, hex_colors):
    for hex_color in hex_colors:
        if col.name == hex_color:
            return [f'background-color: {hex_color}' for c in col.values]
                
def display_hex_colors(hex_colors: List[str]):
    df = pd.DataFrame(hex_colors).T
    df.columns = hex_colors
    df.iloc[0,0:len(hex_colors)] = ""
    display(df.style.apply(lambda x: apply_formatting(x, hex_colors)))
```

```py
hex_list = ['#FFFFFF', '#F0F0F0', '#FCF0D8', '#fdd8a7', '#fdc38d', '#fca16c',
            '#f67b51', '#e7533a', '#cf2518', '#ad0000', '#7f0000', '#440402']
display_hex_colors(hex_list)
```

Example output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: [Standard for ANSI Colors in Terminals](https://bixense.com/clicolors/)

This snippet can show you all the colors in one row:

```
RESET = "\x1b[0m"
print("To reset attributes: \\x1b[0m\n")
for i in range(0, 8):
    print("\x1b[1;3{0}m\\x1b[1;3{0}m{1} \x1b[0;3{0}m\\x1b[0;3{0}m{1} "
          "\x1b[1;4{0};3{0}m\\x1b[1;3{0};4{0}m{1}".format(i, RESET))
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the exact behavior you are asking for can be achieved by wrapping the print() function like so:

```
def print_wrapper(func):
    ansi_reset = '\033[0m'
    ansi_black = '\033[90m'
    ansi_red = '\033[91m'
    ansi_green = '\033[92m'
    ansi_yellow = '\033[93m'
    ansi_blue = '\033[94m'
    ansi_pink = '\033[95m'
    ansi_teal = '\033[96m'
    ansi_gray = '\033[97m'
    ansi_warning = '\033[31;1;4m'
    ansi_error = '\033[31;100m'
    def wrapped_func(*args,**kwargs):
        new_args = args + tuple()
        new_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        for kwarg, kwvalue in kwargs.items(): # Loop through the keyword arguments
            if kwarg == "color":
                if kwvalue == "black":
                    color = ansi_black
                elif kwvalue == "red":
                    color = ansi_red
                elif kwvalue == "green":
                    color = ansi_green
                elif kwvalue == "yellow":
                    color = ansi_yellow
                elif kwvalue == "blue":
                    color = ansi_blue
                elif kwvalue == "pink":
                    color = ansi_pink
                elif kwvalue == "teal":
                    color = ansi_teal
                elif kwvalue == "gray":
                    color = ansi_gray
                elif kwvalue == "warning":
                    color = ansi_warning
                elif kwvalue == "error":
                    color = ansi_error
                new_kwargs = kwargs.copy() # Make a copy of the keyword arguments dict
                del new_kwargs["color"] # Remove color from the keyword arguments dict
        try: # Is the variable color defined?
            color
        except NameError:
            pass
            # no color was specified
        else:
            new_args = ()
            for arg in args:
                new_args += (f"{color}{arg}{ansi_reset}",) # Apply the ANSI escape codes to each non-keyword argument
        return func(*new_args,**new_kwargs)
    return wrapped_func

print = print_wrapper(print) # Apply the wrapper to the print() function

print("This is red.", "And so is this.", color='red')
```

This solution uses the ANSI escape sequences mentioned in several other answers here, but parses and modifies the arguments to print() before outputting them.