# Visualizing Text Classification

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, visualization

Suppose I have a sentence of words, where each word (or character) has an associated numeric value, or color. As an example, this could be coming from an [RNN sentiment classifier](https://blog.openai.com/unsupervised-sentiment-neuron/), which would produce something like:

[image]

I'm looking for a lightweight way of visualizing words/characters in sentences in Jupyter with python. Is there an elegant way of doing this inline in a notebook? I've mostly seen this done with additional javascript, in a separate html file. Note that I'm fine with just a static visualization. I've seen you [can change the color of the font](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42534887/2781958) of each letter, but I'd prefer to just manipulate the background color (fill?), while keeping the text black. I'm just not sure what this is referred to.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a preferred way to achieve this; here is a quick approach that uses a tiny `html` template and `IPython.display.display_html`:

```
from IPython.display import display_html

def to_html(text, r, g, b):
    return "<var style='background-color:rgb({}, {}, {});'>{} </var>".format(
        r, g, b, text
    )

example = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.".split()
res = ''.join(to_html(word, *np.random.randint(0,256,size=3)) for word in example)
display_html(res, raw=True)
```

Resulting in something like this:

```html
<var style='background-color:rgb(144, 237, 221);'>A </var><var style='background-color:rgb(28, 208, 84);'>quick </var><var style='background-color:rgb(142, 241, 214);'>brown </var><var style='background-color:rgb(67, 199, 115);'>fox </var><var style='background-color:rgb(121, 120, 116);'>jumps </var><var style='background-color:rgb(251, 46, 48);'>over </var><var style='background-color:rgb(128, 147, 44);'>the </var><var style='background-color:rgb(48, 215, 5);'>lazy </var><var style='background-color:rgb(239, 90, 48);'>dog. </var>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually quite decent. Minor modification for python 2:


```return "<var style='background-color:rgb(%(r)s, %(g)s, %(b)s);'>%(text)s </var>" % {"text":text,"r":r,"g":g,"b":b}```

Comment: Right, or one could use `str.format` for compatibility with both python 2 and python 3.